# GridSearchCV - Best model without refit

Tags: keras, gridsearchcv

Using `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`, how can you obtain the best model without refitting it to the whole data "in the end" (i.e, expressis verbis having `refit = False`)?

My use case: I tried to build a (poor) work around for estimating neural nets with `tensorflow.keras` to enable early stopping, given pre-specified training- and validation data, within the [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)-framework. However, this work around runs ad absurdum, if in the final step `sklearn` refits to the whole data.

It would be great, if you could please aid me on this issue.

Comment: I suggest u https://github.com/cerlymarco/keras-hypetune

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I implemented it. Seems to work like charm. So, just to be perfectly sure: I pass "savepath=()" to "KerasGridSearch". What happens, is, that the _best_ model from the previous tried-out parameter combinations is saved, _only_ using the training data (I pass on to .search-method), correct? Because, if so, it _exactly_ seems to solve my problem as of now.

Comment: if savepath is not None only the best model is saved to the path you specified

Comment: Great - and it is "just" the model which was trained during the "search", i.e., not like with sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV, where the best model is refitted using the _whole_ data (train and validate) after the best parameter-configurations have been figured out, correct (sorry for insisting, though, I want to perfectly clear on this)? If so: This is so enormous, thank you so much indeed for making this package available!

Comment: yes, refit/retrain is not applied, it's simply the model with the best param configuration saved during the search

Comment: Exactly what I wanted - plus, kgs.best_model and kgs.best_params quasily lets me access data and information like I am used to using sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV. I am so glad you made this work-around and pushed me towards it - thank you once again.